# Why there are two versions of open() in man page?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I'm well aware that man page is separated by sections s.t. `man(2)` talks about system calls and `man(3)` talks about library functions. I'm also aware of the difference between `fopen`(a C library function) and `open`(a system call). But what's the difference `open(2)` and `open(3)`?

It comes to me when I'm looking for `O_DIRECT`(used for direct I/O) in the man page of `open`. Strangely, I find it a valid flag in version [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), but not [open(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open).

This is interesting. I know that `open(2)` is a Linux system call(maybe I should say *nix?). And AFAIK, there is no C library function called `open`. So what's `open(3)`?

I did some search on Web but didn't find anything explicitly answer my question. Does that come from POSIX standards? That's the last thing I can guess. If that's true, what's the difference? Is it that `open(2)` is only implemented in Linux while `open(3)` in both Unix and Linux(because of POSIX). Is that right?

Btw, I'd appreciate it if anyone knows the rationale why `O_DIRECT` is excluded from `open(3)`.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an `open(3)` on my Ubuntu box.  What distribution are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. That's why I am asking what it is. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open(3)` is a description of the POSIX `open` function. The real function on Linux is `open(2)`. The idea is that if you stick to the `open(3)` description then your code should work on another POSIX-compliant system. But if you use functionality of the actual underlying `open(2)` function that is not also in the `open(3)` description (such as  the `O_DIRECT` flag), then you sacrifice the POSIX portability.

Comment: Sounds like a virtual function override in C++ where `open(3)` is the base and `open(2)` is the derived. That said, can we have both versions on a particular distribution(e.g., Ubuntu)? Can I choose to use the POSIX-compliant version? These two functions seem to be included in the same header files, according to man. How can I choose one?

Comment: That's somehow counter-intuitive in the sense that `open(3)` should also be implemented on Linux which is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @EricZ `open(2)` is POSIX compliant. But it has some extensions. The manual page `open(3)` describes the POSIX interface. It isn't a *separate* function at all. It's just a manual page. The POSIX description of a function can never be in part 2 of the manual since those are system specific functions.

Comment: Ok. So since there is a platform specific `O_DIRECT` flag only for `open(2)`, why it's still POSIX-compliant with the "interface" `open(3)`? I guess it is as long as it implements all the semantic of the POSIX version while allowing itself to add some extensions?

Comment: We should say that `open(2)` is POSIX-compliant as long as it doesn't use `O_DIRECT`(and any other extension). Cool.